# Can somebody straighten out this massive CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE confusion?

Tags: php, curl, https, proxy, php-curl

I compare these two URLs in regards to `CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE`:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php :

> Either CURLPROXY_HTTP (default), CURLPROXY_SOCKS4, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5, CURLPROXY_SOCKS4A or CURLPROXY_SOCKS5_HOSTNAME.

https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE.html :

> CURLPROXY_HTTP
>
> HTTP Proxy. Default.
>
> CURLPROXY_HTTPS
>
> HTTPS Proxy. (Added in 7.52.0 for OpenSSL, GnuTLS and NSS)

This massively confuses me. The `CURLPROXY_HTTPS` options seems entirely gone in the PHP manual, but exists in the official cURL one. But my PHP-cURL proxies seem to use HTTPS even with "HTTP" as the proxy type... or at least I certainly hope so...

So if the "HTTP" proxy type "includes" HTTPS, what exactly is the point of the apparently recently added, and confusingly named, `CURLPROXY_HTTPS`?

Comment: `CURLPROXY_HTTP` does work with HTTPS. PHP uses libcurl, but wraps it. When you look exactly `HTTPS Proxy. (Added in 7.52.0 for OpenSSL, GnuTLS and NSS)` was added for use with OpenSSL, GnuTLS and NSS. But this name is *not* that is used in PHP. PHP has its own namespace.

Comment: @MarkusZeller I don't understand. Why add a new option and cal it `_HTTPS` if it's nothing to do with HTTPS? Why not call it `_HTTP_SPECIAL_CASE_FOR_SOME_BROKEN_BUT_COMMON_APPLICATIONS`?

Comment: PHP's Curl is *not* libcurl.

Comment: @MarkusZeller Why is that? It's another thing that makes zero sense to me.

Comment: These or both independent projects by different developers. Ask them!

Comment: @MarkusZeller If it were possible, I would. Why not tell me instead of playing games of riddles and wasting my time and energy?

Comment: I don't get your problem. When you are programming with PHP use it's documentation and not any other.

Comment: @MarkusZeller The PHP documentation is not close to complete. Why would they change random stuff around?

Comment: Again, PHP curl is a wrapper to use libcurl. So it can implement things different than the origin.

Comment: Asking why the php developers made certain choices can be a long and painful game, and the answer is ultimately, "that's php for you." Part of it is because the design philosophy has evolved over years.